# how does pycparser reads the header files listed in includes in C code files?

Tags: python, pycparser

I am trying to parse a C file using pycparser. I am curious to know that while pre-processing the C file does the pycparser reads only those library files which are provided in fake lib folder(if you provide the path of fake lib in cpp_args) or it also reads from the location mentioned in include statements, such as-
in line below

```
#include<folder1/folder2/xyz.h>
```

where will the pycparser search for xyz.h will it only be in FAKE LIB folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will search other directories than the fake folder. If you look in the file `pycparser/__init__.py`, you'll find a function called `preprocess_file` which invokes the C preprocessor on your input file and puts the resulting output in a string, which it then passes to the next function called `parse_file`. The code in each of these functions is fairly clear and well-commented, so give it a read and see if it makes sense.

The fake folder is included only for standard library headers like `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h` and so forth.  Those headers often contain non-portable compiler-specific extensions; chances are, you'll only need to know that there's a function `printf(...)` in order to be able to parse your code.